# How can i convert base64 encoded audio to JSON?

Tags: android, json, audio, encoding, server

MY app have to record a sound and send it to server. All is done upto base64 encoding of recorded sound but can't convert it to JSON.

Could any one please help me to how to do it?

Encoding

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
"/_audio_record.3gp");
                try {
                    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
                    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);



  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),encoded,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
   .show();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Comment: `String json = "{" + "audiobytes : " + encoded + "}";`

Answer (score 0):

if you use retrofit for server connection you can just write function like that

```
@Multipart
@POST("Audios/Upload") //Your EndPoint Here
fun uploadAudio(@Part file: MultipartBody.Part): Call<ReturnType>
```

you can create MultipartBody.Part parameter from your audio file like that :

```
val mediaType = MediaType.parse("audio/*")
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(mediaType, file)
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestFile)
```

where file is obviously your audio file,
hope it helps